# pdo parameter is whole number, append decimal to it

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm running an insert using PDO parameter values, and it's working fine, but I'm getting a lot of zeroes where I should have 0.65, 0.7, etc.

The issue is, its inserting into a decimal field and the sql insert is

```
count(*) / :value
```

In this case, :value is '1' so instead of dividing the count by 1, I want to divide by 1.0 specifically.

Can I append a decimal and zero to my parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps different approach... `ALTER TABLE xxx ALTER COLUMN YYY theColumnName decimal(4,2)` or whatever you need, then it will not add zeros after second decimal place